find triangles that are formed by intersection points of line segments
i'm currently doing a degree in C.S and i want to consult with u guys about the best way to solve my problem.
U don't have to read through my whole code but just in case someone wants to see my classes and methods etc... there u go:
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Represents a point in a 2D Cartesian coordinate system.
 * Each point is defined by an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate.
 */
public final class Point {

    // Fields
    private final double x; // The x-coordinate of the point.
    private final double y; // The y-coordinate of the point.

    /**
     * Constructs a Point with specified x and y coordinates.
     *
     * @param x the x-coordinate of the point
     * @param y the y-coordinate of the point
     */
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a random point within a bounded area.
     * @param xLowerBound the lower bound for the x coordinate
     * @param xUpperBound the upper bound of the x coordinate
     * @param yLowerBound the lower bound for the y coordinate
     * @param yUpperBound the upper bound for the y coordinate
     * @return a new point with x and y between the bounds, exclusive.
     */
    public static Point randomPoint(double xLowerBound, double xUpperBound, double yLowerBound, double yUpperBound) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        double x = rand.nextDouble() * (xUpperBound - xLowerBound) + xLowerBound;
        double y = rand.nextDouble() * (yUpperBound - yLowerBound) + yLowerBound;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * @return the x value.
     */
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @return the y value.
     */
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance from the current point to another point.
     * @param p the other point
     * @return the distance between the points
     */
    public double distance(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - p.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(this.y - p.getY(), 2));
    }

    /**
     * Checks if this point is equal to another point.
     * @param p the other point
     * @return true if the points are the same, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean equals(Point p) {
        return p.x == this.x && p.y == this.y;
    }
}

import biuoop.DrawSurface;

/**
 * Represents a line in a 2D Cartesian coordinate system.
 * Each line is defined by 2 points.
 */
public final class Line {
    // Fields
    private final Point start;
    private final Point end;
    private final double dx;
    private final double dy;
    private final double c;

    /**
     * Constructs a Line with two points.
     *
     * @param start the starting point
     * @param end the ending point
     */
    public Line(Point start, Point end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.dx = start.getX() - end.getX();
        this.dy = end.getY() - start.getY();
        this.c = dy * start.getX() + dx * start.getY();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a Line with four coordinates.
     *
     * @param x1 the x-coordinate of the starting point
     * @param y1 the y-coordinate of the starting point
     * @param x2 the x-coordinate of the ending point
     * @param y2 the y-coordinate of the ending point
     */
    public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        this(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the length of the line.
     *
     * @return the length of the line
     */
    public double length() {
        return start.distance(end);
    }

    /**
     * @return the starting point of the line segment.
     */
    public Point start() {
        return start;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ending point of the line segment.
     */
    public Point end() {
        return end;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the determinant with respect to dx and dy of both lines.
     *
     * @param other the other line
     * @return the determinant
     */
    public double determinant(Line other) {
        return (dy * other.dx) - (dx * other.dy);
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether two lines are parallel.
     *
     * @param other the other line
     * @return true if parallel, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean doParallel(Line other) {
        return determinant(other) == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the intersection point of two lines, or null if there is no intersection.
     *
     * @param other the other line
     * @return the intersection point, or null if no intersection
     */
    public Point intersectionWith(Line other) {
        if (determinant(other) == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        double x = (other.dx * c - dx * other.c) / determinant(other);
        double y = (dy * other.c - other.dy * c) / determinant(other);
        if (isPointOnSegment(new Point(x, y)) && other.isPointOnSegment(new Point(x, y))) {
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a point is on the segment.
     *
     * @param point the point to check
     * @return true if the point is on the segment, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isPointOnSegment(Point point) {
        return point.getX() >= Math.min(start.getX(), end.getX())
                && point.getX() <= Math.max(start.getX(), end.getX())
                && point.getY() >= Math.min(start.getY(), end.getY())
                && point.getY() <= Math.max(start.getY(), end.getY());
    }

    /**
     * Checks if two lines intersect.
     * This method also covers the case where two segments are collinear.
     *
     * @param other the other line
     * @return true if the lines intersect, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isIntersecting(Line other) {
        if (doParallel(other)) {
            return isPointOnSegment(other.start) || isPointOnSegment(other.end)
                    || other.isPointOnSegment(start) || other.isPointOnSegment(end);
        }
        return intersectionWith(other) != null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the midpoint of the line segment.
     *
     * @return the midpoint
     */
    public Point middle() {
        return new Point((start.getX() + end.getX()) / 2, (start.getY() + end.getY()) / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a random line within a rectangular area.
     *
     * @param xLowerBound the lower bound for the x coordinate
     * @param yLowerBound the lower bound for the y coordinate
     * @param xUpperBound the upper bound for the x coordinate
     * @param yUpperBound the upper bound for the y coordinate
     * @return a randomly generated line within the given bounds
     */
    public static Line generateRandomLine(double xLowerBound, double yLowerBound, double xUpperBound, double yUpperBound) {
        Point start = Point.randomPoint(xLowerBound, xUpperBound, yLowerBound, yUpperBound);
        Point end = Point.randomPoint(xLowerBound, xUpperBound, yLowerBound, yUpperBound);
        return new Line(start, end);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a line on a DrawSurface.
     *
     * @param line the line to be drawn
     * @param d the draw surface
     */
    public static void drawLine(Line line, DrawSurface d) {
        int x1 = (int) line.start.getX();
        int x2 = (int) line.end.getX();
        int y1 = (int) line.start.getY();
        int y2 = (int) line.end.getY();
        d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}

import biuoop.GUI;
import biuoop.DrawSurface;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class AbstractArtDrawing {
    public void drawLines() {
        Line[] lines = new Line[10];
        GUI gui = new GUI("Abstract Art", 400, 300);
        DrawSurface d = gui.getDrawSurface();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Line generatedLine = Line.generateRandomLine(0, 0, d.getWidth(), d.getHeight());
            Line.drawLine(generatedLine, d);
            lines[x] = generatedLine;
            //up until now i generated a line and added it to an array of lines
            d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            d.fillCircle((int) generatedLine.middle().getX(), (int) generatedLine.middle().getY(), 3);
            d.setColor(Color.RED);
            //coloring intersection points
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                if (generatedLine.isIntersecting(lines[i])) {
                    d.fillCircle((int) generatedLine.intersectionWith(lines[i]).getX(), (int) generatedLine.intersectionWith(lines[i]).getY(), 3);
                }
            }
        }
        gui.show(d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractArtDrawing example = new AbstractArtDrawing();
        example.drawLines();
    }
}

as U can probably tell from the last code block, they (my university) provided us with GUI library (i'm new to java, i assume it's a library)
and pretty much this code draw line segments on the screen, and up until now i was able to:
1)mark their midpoints in blue
2)mark the intersection points in red
when i run the code it give me something like this:
a random run
i need to mark all the triangles made by the intersection points and the original line segments. the final result should look like this:
desired result
my thought process in general is:
1)save all the intersection points in some sort of a data structure, i thought about an array but that might not be the best approach
2)check for every possible triplet if they're sitting on a spots that create a triangle
3)create new line segments accordingly
my problems are:
1)i can try and use an array, and i can try append the array with a seperate method but that would require lot's of memory and i hope i can do it in a better way (maybe use a different data structure)
2)checking every possible triplet is a wasteful process in terms of space and time complexity and my code would probably be very unreadble
i hope there's a more efficient way to tackle this problem.
thnx for taking the time to read this. i'll appreciate every help i can get :)
well i'm currently on the process of writing a method to save all the intersection points in an array and appending it accordingly. didn't finish the algorithm yet but probably tomorrow i will (i mean i hope i will, maybe i'll need more time to debug)

Did  you consider looking at the  Line and Line2D.* classes in the java.awt.geom package?  There are some useful methods there.  And these classes represent line segments too

sounds interesting, i will def check it out.

And before asking more questions, please take the [tour], to become familiar with the site.
